# Where to import dependency while working with multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, module

Let's say there are two files -  mask.py and main.py.

mask.py has some function that I'm importing into main.py.

So if that function in mask.py which I'm importing has dependency like "os", where should I import os - in mask.py or main.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a scenario as you have stated by using two files `mask.py` and `main.py`.

**mask.py**

```
import os
def some_function():
    os.environ['a_url'] = "something.com" # using dependency as you mentioned
```

**main.py**

```
from mask import some_function

# do something with the function
```

Now, coming to your query, if you use `import os` in `main.py` but not in `mask.py`, you will get **NameError** in `mask.py` saying:

```
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

This is because you need to import any dependency in the same file where it is used. Also, if both of your file uses this dependency, you need to import it in both the files.

Hope this clarifies your query.